# Outlook Redemption: MoveMultiple with activated Cached Mode does not delete origin mail

Tags: email, outlook-redemption

I'm using Redemption to move thousands of mails from an exchange account to a pst store. For moving all the mails I'm using the MoveMultiple method on the folder. The move operation should also work with activated Cached Mode, even when the mail is not loaded to the local user outlook profile.

```
const int MAPI_NO_CACHE = 0x200;
const int MAPI_BEST_ACCESS = 0x10;

var onlineFolder = session.GetFolderFromID (folderId, storeId, MAPI_NO_CACHE + MAPI_BEST_ACCESS);
```

Actually this works just fine and all the mails are moved to the pst file, but the origin mail is not deleted on the exchange server.

Are you guys experiencing the same problem or am I doing something wrong? Do I need to manually start a sync of this folder? Any ideas?

Thx in advance

---

### UPDATE

@DmitryStreblechenko: The problem was, that no exchange items were deleted at all, however they were "copied" correctly to the pst store.

I did some further investigations and it seems that there might be a problem with my exchange account. :'-(

Event when I move the Items via my Outlook client they are only copied to the pst store - the origin mails remain in the exchange store. I don't now why because I don't get an error or ComException. It looks like that everything worked correctly, but the opposite ist true. Btw. the deletion of the mail works as expected.

I now switched to a different exchange account and with that the move to the pst store with activated Cached Mode works perfectly. I don't know why Outlook is struggling with my primary exchange account. I dont' get any errors.

How do you investigate these "errors"?

Comment: Do you see items in Outlook after syncing?

Comment: Do you mean the locally cached items are deleted from both the local OST file and the online mailbox, but the old emails not present in OST are not deleted from the online mailbox? Or that no Exchange items are deleted at all? Or that they are deleted from the online mailbox but not the OST store?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I've updated my question and added further information in the UPDATE section

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev : After the operation I still can see the mails in my exchange web access. After a fresh sync the items also appear in my Outlook client.

Comment: Try to close Outlook, rename the old OST file, then start Outlook again and let it sync your mailbox. Could be cached store corruption...

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I tried that already and also created a new profile. All my attempts lead to no effect. I think something is wrong with my "Deleted Items" folder. When I try to empty it, I get the following message:

Some items cannot be deleted. They were either moved or already deleted, or access was denied

As it is not possible to clean the folder in my Outlook client, I tried to empty it via web access. If I delete the mail in the deleted items folder, the mails gets again displayed after a browser refresh.

So this may be an Outlook Issue and has nothing to do with Redemption

Comment: Interesting... Does it work OK if you connect to that mailbox from a different machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196427/discussion-between-pego-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Answer (score 0):

**CONCLUSION:**
After some investigations I found out, that something was broken with my "Deleted Items" folder of the exchange account and the problem was not related to any client or Redemption.

**FIX:**
Unfortunately I was not able to empty the "Deleted Items" folder on any client or the exchange web access I wrote a little script to delete each item programmatically. After that I created a new Outlook profile and restarted Outlook in safe mode and voilà suddenly I can now empty the "Deleted Items" folder on any client. Even the move operation to PST file works as expected - the origin mails are deleted in the source directory.